# How to count vowels and consonants in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that takes a user inputted sentence and outputs a count of both Vowels and Consonants in python. My Vowel counter works without any problems but the consonant count always returns 0. I have no idea why.

```
def checkvowelsConsonants():
    consonants = 0
    vowelscount = 0
    index = 0
    sentence = input("Please input your sentence here. This sentence must contain a speical character eg, - ? etc.")
    Vowels = (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"])
    vowelcount = 0
    while index < len(sentence):
        if sentence[index] in Vowels:
            vowelcount += 1
        index += 1
    while index < len(sentence):
        if sentence[index] not in Vowels:
            consonants += 1
        index += 1
    print("The number of vowels is", vowelcount, "and consonants is", consonants)
```

here is an output I recieved for refrence

Please input your sentence here. This sentence must contain a speical character eg, - ? etc.aaaaaaaasssssssssss
The number of vowels is 8 and consonants is 0

Comment: What is the value of `index` after your vowels are already counted and you are about to start counting consonants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def classify_letter(string: str):
    vowels = 0
    consonants = 0
    for i in string:
        if i.casefold() in 'aeiou':
            vowels += 1
        elif i.casefold() in 'qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm':
            consonants += 1
    return vowels, consonants
```

or with a list comprehension

```
def classify_letter(strng: str) -> tuple:
    x = [i.casefold() in "aeiou" for i in strng if i.casefold() in string.ascii_lowercase]
    return x.count(True), x.count(False)
```

^ I acknowledge this might not be the best way to implement that, im open to suggestions to make it shorter and optimized!

when passed `"hello-"` these both return:

```
(2,3)
```

Comment: Why use `i` for the name of the element when iterating? Also, you should generally use `str.casefold()` for case-insensitive comparisons, not `str.lower()`.

Comment: `i` is just a habit, `iteration`; thanks for the `casefold()` suggestion, let me test and edit!

Comment: _`i` is just a habit_ I would say it's a convention, when I see `i`, `j`, etc. I immediately think of iterating over indices, coordinates... Also, you changed the function name, but didn't make it PEP 8-compliant.

Comment: would `classifyLetter` be compliant?

Comment: Quoting from [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/): _Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

Variable names follow the same convention as function names.

mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility._

Comment: wait pep8 doesn't allow camelcase? Damn didnt know, edited to somewhat match

Comment: `True if i.casefold() in "aeiou" else False` --> `i.casefold() in "aeiou"`. Also, you would need to casefold both strings.

Comment: You don't really need the `.isalpha()`, by the way.

Comment: without it it would return add `False` for things like `"-"` though right?

Comment: You're right, although I believe there's still an issue, since `str.isalpha()` is much broader than just "is it one of the letters A-Z". It would be better to check if the character is in [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase), for example. I think that using a list comprehension for this offers few benefits.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that should look work cleanly!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you don't reset your index variable after counting vowels. Therefore, when it gets to the consonant loop, the index variable is already set to whatever the sentence length is, and the consonant loop is skipped. Something like this would fix it:

```
def checkvowelsConsonants():
    consonants = 0
    vowelscount = 0
    index = 0
    sentence = input("Please input your sentence here. This sentence must contain a speical character eg, - ? etc.")
    Vowels = (["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"])
    vowelcount = 0
    while index < len(sentence):
        if sentence[index] in Vowels:
            vowelcount += 1
        index += 1
    index = 0
    while index < len(sentence):
        if sentence[index] not in Vowels:
            consonants += 1
        index += 1
    print("The number of vowels is", vowelcount, "and consonants is", consonants)
```

Notice how after the first loop, there is the
`index = 0`
line.
This resets the variable so that it is ready to go through the loop again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue, as was pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64760213/how-to-count-vowels-and-consonants-in-python#comment114502470_64760213), is that the `index` variable is not reset after counting the vowels, and so your program doesn't iterate over the string again to count consonants.

In fact, the `index` variable should be done away with entirely. There are a few other issues with the code, too: The most important one is the fact that you're counting anything which isn't a vowel as a consonant. The string `','` isn't a vowel, but it certainly isn't a consonant.

Here is a refactored version of your program:

```py
def count_vowels_consonants(str_in: str):
    vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'}
    consonants = {'w', 'm', 'j', 'r', 'z', 'c', 'h', 'l', 'p', 'k', 's', 'b', 'y', 'n', 'f', 'q', 't', 'd', 'x', 'g',
                  'v', 'L', 'S', 'N', 'Q', 'F', 'B', 'R', 'Z', 'X', 'J', 'D', 'H', 'V', 'C', 'P', 'G', 'K', 'T', 'Y',
                  'M', 'W'}
    num_vowels = 0
    num_consonants = 0

    for char in str_in:
        if char in vowels:
            num_vowels += 1
        elif char in consonants:
            num_consonants += 1

    return num_vowels, num_consonants


sentence = input('Please input your sentence (this sentence must contain a speical character eg, - ? etc.): ')

sentence_num_vowels, sentence_num_consonants = count_vowels_consonants(sentence)

print('vowels: {}, consonants: {}'.format(sentence_num_vowels, sentence_num_consonants))
```

I also improved the names, and moved code around to ensure the function is pure and easy to reuse.